# Python pandas DataFrame memory error

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

I am working with big csv files, that contains 700k x 200 cells.
When I read the file (one at the time) it consumes about 2GB out of 13GB usable RAM. After that I am trying to make new df variable (I need to keep both of them), with only 30 columns. Similar code I have in my project, here are some modifications like not real names of columns or file name:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
...
some calculations on df
...
columns = list(range(30))
df2 = df[columns]
```

In the last operation here I get below error:

```
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-
     packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1958, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2003, in _getitem_array
    return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1925, in take
    self._consolidate_inplace()
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3138, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._protect_consolidate(f)
  File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3127, in _protect_consolidate
    result = f()
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3136, in f
    self._data = self._data.consolidate()
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3573, in consolidate
    bm._consolidate_inplace()
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3578, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4525, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
File "C:\Python36\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4548, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = new_values[argsort]
MemoryError
```

The memory never goes above 3GB of usage. I guess it should not be a problem with lack of memory. As far as I know, Python hasn't any memory limitations beside comupter's RAM.

If you need more info please ask, before downvoting. I will then edit may question. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=list(range(30)))`?

Comment: I need both dfs. Calculations are performed after reading file. I will edit question.